# Reinitialise asio::socket in class

Tags: c++, oop, boost, boost-asio, initialization-list

I found out, that if I want to use `boost::socket` as a class member I must define it using **initialization lists** and it must be defined even **before constructor dispatches**.
That means, that I have to prove its constructor with some dummy parameter and I will need to reinitialise it again, when I have data I need.

#### client.hpp

```
class SocketClient {
    private:
       int port; //Port, currently unused
       boost::asio::io_service io_service;  //This is my "dummy" parameter
       boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator;
       boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock; //Socket class instance
     
    public:
       void init(const char*, const char* );
       SocketClient::SocketClient():sock(io_service){};  //Giving empty "io_service" to  the "sock"
       bool read(int bytes, char *text);
       bool send(int length, char *text);
       bool send(std::string text);
       unsigned int timeout;
};
```

Later, when `init()` method is called, I need to supply the `sock` with initialised `io_service`. I have no idea how to do this:

#### client.h

```
void SocketClient::init(const char* ip_a, const char* port_a) {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(ip_a, port_a);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    //Error (unsuported operator =):
    sock=boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
    //Error (term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments):
    sock(io_service);
}
```

[Here you can see whole project](http://u8.8u.cz/code/sockets/), with nothing removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the sokect initialized , now only need to connect

```
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), ip_a,port_a);
tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
sock.connect(*iterator);
```